# Binding Modified schema file to xsd file in livecycle designer tool

Tags: xsd, adobe, livecycle, xdp-pdf

i am using adobe livecycle 8.2 for documents template generation,
i am new to adobe livecycle designer tool.

in my template we are using xsd file to bind data to xdp file.
i have done some changes in schema file.
and want to reflect changes in my designer tool.

if i create new Data Source then all my previous bindings are lost.
i want to keep all my previous binding and also want to bind newly added field.

please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Data view tab right click on the current schema root node and select Connection Properties.

There you can update the location of the new XSD file and this way you'll preserve all the bindings